# How can we store any language of text(english, hindi, spanish e.t.c.) and retrieve same value from database

Tags: java, php, mysql

We allow user to entry any language in text field and that valu i store in database and we return same language to user when user view in browser.

when i passed "Sant Juliã  De Lã²ria" value in database and when i retrieve from database then display like this "Sant Juli�� De L��ria"

How can we display user to same value as user input in text fields

Comment: You have a UTF-8/encoding issue.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but I suspect it's going to have to do with the encoding of the column in question.

Comment: You are having encoding issue. Keep UTF-8 encoding through out the application.

Comment: yes i already encode with UTF-8 is there any issue with fields collation...

Comment: @MehulDudhat: How would we know? You haven't given us any information about your DB other than the vendor.

Comment: Obligatory link: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) Fundamentally: Make sure the *page* is encoded correctly, the server says what the encoding is, the DB is using the same encoding (or you're intentionally transliterating), etc., etc.

Comment: i am encoding all value with UTF8 and i provide db collation in database utf8mb4_general_ci, is there any issue with this collation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code before insert

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: it's show me error in back-end java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD  D...' for column 'Text_comment' at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)

Comment: @MehulDudhat are you running this code in your java code?

Comment: yes i execute in java with tomcat server with mysql database

Answer (score 0):

If server is in your hands change mysqld configuration (my.cnf file)

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

then change defaults coalocation in your db, tables